# Converting the architecture of a Firebase snapshot value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to import data from Firebase right after my React application starts.

```
firebase.database().ref('rooms/room0/messages').on('value', (snapshot) => {
      let roomMessages = snapshot.val()
      if  (roomMessages !== null) {this.setState({messages: [roomMessages]})}
      console.log(roomMessages)
```

---

The problem is that I cannot make Firebase to return my messages as a simple array of objects. After I run the code above it inserts this object into my state:

```
{message0: {...}, message1: {...}}
```

I want to receive the data like this:

```
{{...}, {...}}
```

How can I achieve that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't really change the way that data comes back in a snapshot.  You can, however, write code to convert the data to the format you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's common to work with arrays Firebase allows for that... Try something like this:

```
firebase.database()
  .ref('rooms/room0/messages')
  .once('value')
  .then(snapshot => {
    const messages = [];
    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
      messages.push({
        id: childSnapshot.key,
        ...childSnapshot.val()
      })
    })
  })
```

You will now have an array of objects in the `messages` array...